# Javascript - How to check if current time is between two different times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying programmatically check if the current time for my web application is between two predefined times. I don't know how to get the current time and then set variables that store two predefined times. The pseudo code would look like this

```
if(currentTime < shiftStart && currentTime <shiftEnd)
{
   shift = 2
}
```

But how do I declare and setup the variables so the code works correctly.

Comment: How are defined your times ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: Shouldn't the first comparison be using `>` instead of `<`?

Comment: Use simple numerical timestamps.

Answer (score 5):

```
var now = Date.now();
var time1 = //whatever time1 is
var time2 = //whatever time2 is

if (now > time1 && now < time2)
{
    alert("blah"):
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`var diff = date.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();` gives you the difference between the time in milliseconds.

```
var diff1=shiftStart.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
var diff2=shiftEnd.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

if(diff1 < 0 && diff2 > 0 ) 
{
    shift = 2;
}
```